# Redux not returning object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am finding myself in a rabbit hole lol.  I am making a call to gett a list of objects and the call is successful, and I can see the data getting returned back.  But I am not understanding why columnDefs is not getting updated with the success data.

```
defaultState = {
  columnDefs: []
}

export default function MarketReducer(state = defaultState,action ){
  switch (action.type){
        case GET_MARKETING_LIST:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                columnDefs: [],
            });
        case GET_MARKETING_SUCCESS:
           return Object.assign({}, state, {
                columnDefs: action.payload.data.column_headers.columnDefs,
            });
        case GET_MARKETING_FAIL:
            return Object.assign({}, state,{
                error: action.error,
                columnDefs: [],
            });
        default:
        return state;
  }
}

export function getMarketingProspects() {
        return {
            type: GET_MARKETING_LIST,
            payload: {
                request: {
                    url: "/marketing/customers",
                    method: "GET"
                }
            }
        };
}
```

Then I have a button that is triggering getMarketingProspects().  Problem is that store is not getting updated.

Comment: Why would `getMarketingProspects` update the store? It returns a hard coded object and doesn't touch the store.

Comment: You have no `switch` statement. And why pass in a payload if you're not going to use it?

Comment: @Andy, sorry I do have a switch, forgot to put on here, ill update my description

Comment: @Quentin what hardcoded object?

Comment: You're passing in `payload`, but you're updating state with an object that only has an empty array as the value of the property. `payload` isn't being used at all. @chewie

Comment: @chewie — The one created by the literal immediately after the `return` keyword

Comment: @Quentin I am not following.  I am assigning the payload at success and assigning that to columnDefs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason as to why it was not setting it to the store is because the actions were named different, i had to add "LIST" to success and failed, this then worked.

GET_MARKETING_LIST:
GET_MARKETING_LIST_SUCCESS:
GET_MARKETING_LIST_FAIL:

Answer (score -2):

```
export function getMarketingProspects() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_MARKETING_LIST,
      payload: {
        request: {
          url: "/marketing/customers",
          method: "GET"
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

now, on the action button you should dispatch the getMarketingProspects function. Like this.

```
onClick={()=> useDispatch(getMarketingProspects())}
```